Does the time-energy uncertainty principle play a role in very fast nuclear reactions?
In the context of very fast nuclear reactions like those modeled by the intranuclear cascade INC, like gammas interacting with some materials at 100MeV. Does the time-energy uncertainty principle plays a role in the broadening of the energy spectrum of the emitted particles ? If not, can you explain why ?
I know that some of these reactions could take place in like $10^{-22}s$. Is the broadening of the gaussians of the emitted neutrons/protons due to the uncertainty principle ?
$$ \Delta E > \frac{\hbar}{2\Delta t } = \frac{6.5821 \, E-15}{2 * 10^{-22}} = 3.29 \text{MeV}$$
This is a very rough calculation but does someone has any idea if that's correct or not ?
I always studied this relation from the detector's POV, like if the particle is going too fast and the detection time is very short, then the energy won't be very precise.
